# discord.py bot not responding in channel text

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My python chat bot connect to the discord server and when a user DM the bot it replay fine, but it only works in DMS.

As you see in the code it should respond when someone type "hi", but when someone types "hi" in the text channel, it doesn't reply.

**i gave the bot administrator permissions**

this is my code :

```
# IMPORT DISCORD.PY. ALLOWS ACCESS TO DISCORD'S API.
import discord

bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.author == client.user:
         return

     if  message.content.startswith('hi'):
              await message.channel.send('#your response here')


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

I want the bot to reply in any channel when someone types "hi". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use both the client syntax and bot syntax in the same code. You have to choose either one.

You can use one of these 2:

1. Client syntax (Old)

   ```
    import discord

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return


        if message.content.startswith('hi'):
            await message.channel.send('#your response here')

    client.run("TOKEN")
   ```
2. Bot Syntax (New)

   ```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.members = True
    intents.message_content = True

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?', intents=intents)

    @bot.command()
    async def hi(ctx):
        await ctx.send('#your response here')

    bot.run("TOKEN")
   ```

It's your choice to choose either one, though the new syntax is more widespread now. However, the new syntax does need a command prefix, so you have to say, for example, "?hi" instead of "hi".

Also remember to turn on intents in the discord developer portal.